# Import the seed phrases generated in Electrum

Tags: electrum, mnemonic-seed, import

To which wallets can I import the seed phrases generated in Electrum?

Answer (score 0):

Probably none? Nearly none?

So far as I know, Electrum uses its own system of seed phrases which it's developers consider to be better than the BIP39 system used by many other wallets.

I believe Electrum has some compatibility features that must be specifically enabled. Most users probably don't do that unless they anticipate the need.

The developers of Sparrow Wallet [commented](https://github.com/sparrowwallet/sparrow/issues/59)

> Although it would be relatively simple to implement (as you note, Sparrow already supports the Electrum seed format internally), I've held off on doing so because:
>
> - it might be confusing to have two types of seed lists to choose from
> - I'm not sure it's a good idea to keep supporting such an isolated 'standard'

BlueWallet *[might](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5259678.0)* have support for Electrum seed phrases.